# change detection not working on angular input debounce

Tags: angular, input, debouncing, angular-changedetection

I have an input and on the debounce (half a second after finishing typing) I'm setting a variable. I want this variable to change some html. It works but only after I finish typing, then type and start again. So on the second go around it works. I'd like it to happen on the first time.

Here's my html:

```
  <loader *ngIf="searchLoader"></loader>
  <input
    #searchInput
    placeholder="Search pages"
    [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
    (keyup)="debounceSearch.next($event.target.value)"
  >
```

and my ts:

```
  debounceSearch: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.debounceSearch
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.searchLoader = true;
        this.searchDocs();
      });
  }
```

So in the above, the `<loader></loader>` only shows up after the second debounce. Its odd because I set the variable to true immediately.

- debounceTime comes from an rxjs operator `import { debounceTime, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";` essentially after a set amount of time (500ms) it will trigger what ever is in the `.subscribe` function.

I've tried using the change detector ref and detect changes in the subscribe function but it didn't work for me.

Comment: It seems to work for me (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lihq9i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you're attempting to assign a value when nothing has triggered the `Subscription` yet.

Take this example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebyrsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) 
If you open up the console log, you will end up seeing this in the following order

- ngOnChanges called
- ngOnInit called.
- turnOn is undefined

*Notice the console.log inside the subscription doesn't get called.*

Since nothing is triggering the subscription, the inner callback is never called. One solution to your current situation is to assign the default `this.searchLoader = true or false;` outside of the `ngOnInit`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <p *ngIf="turnOn">I'm a ninja</p>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;

  turnOn: boolean;
  switchSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('ngOnChanges called.');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit called.');
    this.switchSubject.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('subscription activated.');
      this.turnOn = true;
    })
    console.log(`turnOn is ${this.turnOn}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: He actually does triggers subscription through `(keyup)="debounceSearch.next($event.target.value)"` Your example will also work when you will trigger subscription the same way https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxbghl?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui, I should have been a bit more clear with my point above. What I was trying to point out is nothing within subscription will trigger until the first action (event) has taken place.